# process sql query results

Tags: php, mysql

I got a table named "**Serials**" with 5 comumns
**Serial, Code, Name, Redeemed, Redeem_date**

i am selecting some fields from that table with this query:

```
$query = "SELECT `Name`,`Redeemed`,`Redeem_date` FROM `Serials` WHERE `Serial` = '$serial' AND `Code` = '$code'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();
```

But i dont know how to pass these values in the following variables so i can use them in if statements later

```
$name= //retured value from column Name
$redeemed= //retured value from column Redeemed
$redeem_date= //retured value from column Redeem_date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just like this..

```
// Your query here..
$query = "SELECT `Name`,`Redeemed`,`Redeem_date` FROM `Serials` WHERE `Serial` = '$serial' AND `Code` = '$code'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->query();

//fetch data and stored into variables
while($row = fetch_array($results)){
  $name = $row['Name'];
  $redeemed = $row['Redeemed'];
  $redeem_date = $row['Redeem_date'];
}
```

Comment: `mysql_*`? `PDO` or `mysqli_`, `mysql_` functions are deprecated.

Comment: Took me some time but got it. 
It needs to go like this and it works:  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){ 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try something like this :

```
<?php
$result = $db->query("SELECT `Name`,`Redeemed`,`Redeem_date` FROM `Serials` WHERE `Serial` = '$serial' AND `Code` = '$code'");
while (list($name, $redeemed, $redeem_date) = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
 // DO SOMETHING
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = $db->fetch()) {

$name= $row['name'];
$redeemed= $row['redeemed'];
$redeem_date= $row['redeem_date'];

}
```

this one might fetch your results and assign to vars